# micrometer tracing with zipkin doesn't show all span in a trace

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, zipkin, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I'm using spring boot 3 and try to migrate to micrometer tracing   !

In the zipkin interface, it shows me each trace with id and details, but doen't show me the spans ...

I use this dependencies :

<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I set this properties:
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://localhost:9411
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0